Tensorflow model stuck at 10% accuracy on fashionmnist
I'm working on trying to implement a capsule network in tf2. However when running the code the model never exceeds an accuracy of 10% on fashionmnist and if I use the included loss function the loss goes negative after 1 epoch. I've validated that the data I have is correct and a tf1 implementation works. There is no augmentation done on the data either, I only divide it by 255 and shuffle before training.
I use a batch size of 16, 28x28x1 image size, 10 epochs, 1e-05 learning rate and 10 output classes
# coding: utf-8
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Plotting library
import numpy as np  # Algebra library
# import tensorflow as tf # Tensorflow
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf  # Tensorflow
import os  # Folder management library
# import pandas as pd # Essentially puts data in spreadsheeet
# from PIL import Image # Image processing library
import scipy.misc  # General stats functions
import random  # Pseudo random number generator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  # To split data into train, test, validation
import pickle  # Serializing module.
from matplotlib.image import imread  # Plotting images
# New libraries ------------------------------------------------------------
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
import tensorflow as tf2
import ast
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Plotting library
import numpy as np  # Algebra library
# import tensorflow as tf  # Tensorflow
import os  # Folder management library
import random  # Pseudo random number generator

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  # To split data into train, test, validation
import pickle  # Serializing module.
import h5py


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Capsule Network Training Script')
    parser.add_argument('--train_data', type=str, required=True, help='Path to the training data H5 file')
    parser.add_argument('--val_data', type=str, required=True, help='Path to the validation data H5 file')
    parser.add_argument('--folder_name', type=str, default='PixelArt', help='Folder name for saving models and logs')
    parser.add_argument('--input_dimensions', type=int, nargs='+', default=[28, 28, 1], help='Initial learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--num_classes', type=int, default=5, help='Number of classes')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=16, help='Batch size for training')
    parser.add_argument('--n_epochs', type=int, default=10, help='Number of epochs')
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.001, help='Initial learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--class_names', type=str, nargs='+',
                        default=['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5'], help='List of class names')
    return parser.parse_args()


def load_data(path):
    with h5py.File(path, 'r') as f:
        x = f['image'][()]
        y = f['label'][()]
    return np.array(x), np.array(y)


# Print tensorflow version
print('Tensorflow version:', tf.__version__)

strategy = tf2.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

with strategy.scope():
    # FUNCTIONS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class predictions(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
        def __init__(self, caps_Lminus1, dims_Lminus1, caps_L, dims_L, name=None):
            super(predictions, self).__init__(name=name)
            self.caps_Lminus1 = caps_Lminus1
            self.dims_Lminus1 = dims_Lminus1
            self.caps_L = caps_L
            self.dims_L = dims_L
            init_sigma = 0.1
            W_init = tf.random.normal(shape=(1, caps_Lminus1, caps_L, dims_L, dims_Lminus1),
                                      stddev=init_sigma, dtype=tf.float32, name="W_init")
            self.W = tf.Variable(W_init, name="W")

        def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
            output_Lminus1, batch_size, weight_sharing, grid_cells_Lminus1, caps_L = inputs

            if tf.get_static_value(weight_sharing) == False:
                output_Lminus1 = tf.squeeze(output_Lminus1, axis=[1, 4], name="output_Lminus1")

            # Tile W for the batch
            W_tiled = tf.tile(self.W, [batch_size, grid_cells_Lminus1, 1, 1, 1], name="W_tiled")
            # -1 means add another dimension to the end of tensor
            output_expanded_Lminus1 = tf.expand_dims(output_Lminus1, -1, name="output_expanded_Lminus1")
            # 2 means add another dimension to the 2th position of tensor
            output_tile_Lminus1 = tf.expand_dims(output_expanded_Lminus1, 2, name="output_tile_Lminus1")
            # 1 in shape argument means keep dimensions from caps1_output_tile
            output_tiled_Lminus1 = tf.tile(output_tile_Lminus1, [1, 1, caps_L, 1, 1], name="output_tiled_Lminus1")
            # Get prediction tensor (3rd array) by using t.matmul
            predicted_L = tf.matmul(W_tiled, output_tiled_Lminus1, name="predicted_L")

            return predicted_L

        def get_config(self):
            config = super(predictions, self).get_config()
            config.update({
                "caps_Lminus1": self.caps_Lminus1,
                "dims_Lminus1": self.dims_Lminus1,
                "caps_L": self.caps_L,
                "dims_L": self.dims_L,
            })
            return config


    def routing(caps_Lminus1, caps_L, batch_size, iterations, predicted_L, name=None):

        with tf.name_scope(name, default_name="routing"):
            # initialize the raw routing weights to zero
            # The two extra 1s is so that raw_weights and weighted_predictions have the same size
            raw_weights = tf.zeros([batch_size, caps_Lminus1, caps_L, 1, 1], dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
                                   name="raw_weights")

            for r in range(0, iterations):
                # c_i = softmax(b_i)
                routing_weights = tf.nn.softmax(raw_weights, dim=2, name="routing_weights")
                # weighted sum of all the predicted output vectors for each second-layer capsule
                weighted_predictions = tf.multiply(routing_weights, predicted_L, name="weighted_predictions")
                weighted_sum = tf.reduce_sum(weighted_predictions, axis=(1), keepdims=True, name="weighted_sum")

                # Squash weighted_sum (s_j) to get output for 2nd capsules (v_j)
                output_L = squash(weighted_sum, axis=-2, name="output_L")

                # Make caps2_output same size as predicted_caps
                output_tiled_L = tf.tile(output_L,
                                         [1, caps_Lminus1, 1, 1, 1],
                                         name="output_tiled_L")
                # the 1 in the shape argument in tf.tile means keep dimension from caps2_output.

                # Dot Product
                agreement = tf.matmul(predicted_L, output_tiled_L, transpose_a=True, name="agreement")
                # Update raw_weights
                raw_weights = tf.add(raw_weights, agreement, name="raw_weights")

            return output_L, routing_weights


    # safe_norm taken from Aurélien Geron
    def squash(s, axis=-1, epsilon=1e-7, name=None):

        with tf.name_scope(name, default_name="squash"):
            squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(s), axis=axis,
                                         keepdims=True)
            safe_norm = tf.sqrt(squared_norm + epsilon)
            squash_factor = squared_norm / (1. + squared_norm)
            unit_vector = s / safe_norm
            return squash_factor * unit_vector


    # safe_norm taken from Aurélien Geron
    def safe_norm(s, axis=-1, epsilon=1e-7, keep_dims=False, name=None):

        with tf.name_scope(name, default_name="safe_norm"):
            squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(s), axis=axis,
                                         keep_dims=keep_dims)
            return tf.sqrt(squared_norm + epsilon)


    def margin_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        """
        Margin loss for Eq.(4). When y_true[i, :] contains not just one `1`, this loss should work too. Not test it.
        :param y_true: [None, n_classes]
        :param y_pred: [None, num_capsule]
        :return: a scalar loss value.
        """
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)

        L = y_true * K.square(K.maximum(0., 0.9 - y_pred)) + \
            0.5 * (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(0., y_pred - 0.1))

        return K.mean(K.sum(L, 1))


    # THE CAPSULE NETWORK ARCHITECTURE ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # input ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    X = layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
    y = layers.Input(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32, name="y")


    def shuffle_data(x, y):
        indices = np.arange(x.shape[0])
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        x_shuffled = x[indices]
        y_shuffled = y[indices]
        return x_shuffled, y_shuffled

    def main():
        args = parse_args()

        print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
        np.random.seed(42)
        # tf.random.set_seed(42)

        # Load your data
        x_train, y_train = load_data(args.train_data)
        x_val, y_val = load_data(args.val_data)

        # Shuffle training data
        x_train, y_train = shuffle_data(x_train, y_train)

        # Shuffle validation data if needed
        x_val, y_val = shuffle_data(x_val, y_val)
        dims = args.input_dimensions

        x_train = x_train.reshape((-1, dims[0], dims[1], dims[2])).astype('float32') / 255.
        x_test = x_val.reshape((-1, dims[0], dims[1], dims[2])).astype('float32') / 255.
        y_train = y_train.astype('float32')
        y_test = y_val.astype('float32')

        print(x_train.shape)
        print(y_train.shape)
        print(x_test.shape)
        print(y_test.shape)

        n_samples = 6

        # Adjust the number of columns in the subplot grid
        plt.figure(figsize=(18, 11))
        for i in range(min(n_samples, len(x_train))):
            plt.subplot(1, n_samples, i + 1)  # Set columns equal to the number of samples
            sample_image = x_train[i]
            plt.imshow(sample_image)
            plt.title(y_train[i])
            plt.axis("off")
        plt.show()

        print('Labels:', y_train[:n_samples])

        # Placeholder for the input images (batch size, length, width, greyscale).
        # Batch size, length, and width are set to None as they can vary.
        X = layers.Input(shape=(None, None, dims[2]), dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
        y = layers.Input(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32, name="y")

        # Conv Layer ---------------------------------------------------------------
        conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=9, strides=(3, 3),
                              padding="valid", activation='relu')(X)

        # Convcaps Layer -----------------------------------------------------------
        # No. of dimenions a single capsule contains.
        convcaps_dims = 8
        # No. of capsules per grid cell.
        convcaps_caps_types = 32
        convcaps = layers.Conv2D(filters=convcaps_caps_types * convcaps_dims, kernel_size=5, strides=(2, 2),
                                 padding="valid", activation='relu')(conv1)
        # Length and width of convaps layer.
        convcaps_grid_length = tf.shape(convcaps)[1]
        convcaps_grid_width = tf.shape(convcaps)[2]
        convcaps_grid_cells = convcaps_grid_length * convcaps_grid_width
        # Total No. capsules in convcaps layer.
        convcaps_caps = convcaps_caps_types * convcaps_grid_cells
        # Reshape convcaps so that it is easier to work with.
        convcaps_reshape = tf.reshape(convcaps, [-1, convcaps_caps, convcaps_dims], name="convcaps_reshape")
        # Squash convcaps with squashing function.
        convcaps_output = squash(convcaps_reshape, name="convcaps_output")

        batch_size = tf.shape(X)[0]
        caps1_caps = args.num_classes
        caps1_dims = 16

        caps1_predictions = predictions(convcaps_caps_types, convcaps_dims,
                                        caps1_caps, caps1_dims, "caps1_predictions")(
            [convcaps_output, batch_size, True, convcaps_grid_cells, caps1_caps])
        caps1_output, routing1 = routing(convcaps_caps, caps1_caps,
                                         batch_size, 5, caps1_predictions, "routing1")

        # Capsule Accuracy ----------------------------------------------------------
        # Lengths of capsules represent probability that entity exists.
        lengths = safe_norm(caps1_output, axis=-2, name="lengths")
        # Round lengths to determine predicted class.
        lengths_rounded = tf.round(lengths, name="lengths_rounded")
        # Remove dimensions of size 1 from lengths_rounded
        y_predictions = tf.squeeze(lengths_rounded, axis=[1], name="y_predictions")  # 1, 2, 3

        # If y matches y_predictions than 1 otherwise 0.
        correct = tf.equal(y, y_predictions, name="correct")
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32), name="accuracy")

        # Custom loss----------------------------------------------------------------
        def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
            m_plus = 0.9
            m_minus = 0.1
            lambda_ = 0.5

            T = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=[-1, 1], name="T")
            # Compute norm of each capsule in digitcaps
            caps3_output_norm = safe_norm(y_pred, axis=-2, keep_dims=True, name="caps3_output_norm")

            present_error_raw = tf.square(tf.maximum(0., m_plus - caps3_output_norm), name="present_error_raw")
            present_error = tf.reshape(present_error_raw, shape=(-1, caps1_caps), name="present_error")
            # -1 tells reshape to calculate the size of this dimension.

            absent_error_raw = tf.square(tf.maximum(0., caps3_output_norm - m_minus), name="absent_error_raw")
            absent_error = tf.reshape(absent_error_raw, shape=(-1, caps1_caps), name="absent_error")
            # -1 tells reshape to calculate the size of this dimension.

            # Compute Margin Loss
            L = tf.add(T * present_error, lambda_ * (1.0 - T) * absent_error, name="L")
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(L, axis=1), name="loss")
            tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

            return loss

        # Optimizer ---------------------------------------------------------------
        model = Model(X, lengths_rounded)
        opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=args.learning_rate)
        model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=margin_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Define the checkpoint callback
        checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            'models/weights.h5',  # Path where to save the model weights
            monitor='val_loss',  # Monitor the validation loss
            save_best_only=True,  # Save only the best model
            mode='min',  # Mode for monitoring (minimize the monitored quantity)
            verbose=1  # Print out messages when saving the model
        )

        model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=args.batch_size, epochs=args.n_epochs, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                  callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()


The repo's I'm referencing are: https://github.com/AmanjotBhullar/ALED_TF2/blob/main/retrain_script_tf2.ipynb
and the tf1 repo is:
https://github.com/AmanjotBhullar/Routing-Path-Visualization/blob/master/Routing_Path_Visualization.ipynb
I've scaled the model down to just 1 output capsule for simplicity. Here is an example from the first epoch when using the my_loss_fn:
2997/3000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: -5.7319 - accuracy: 0.09942
this was the one from the github repo, I then came across another github repo that uses margin loss and tried that as well where I get:
3000/3000 [==============================] - 55s 17ms/step - loss: 2.3423 - accuracy: 0.0993 - val_loss: 1.9753 - val_accuracy: 0.1027
3000/3000 [==============================] - 58s 19ms/step - loss: 1.9491 - accuracy: 0.0993 - val_loss: 1.9099 - val_accuracy: 0.1027
I've tried different loss functions, I tried to change the model output from caps1_output to lengths and lengths_rounded but then I get an error saying:
ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 10 but is 16 for '{{node my_loss_fn/present_error}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](my_loss_fn/present_error_raw, my_loss_fn/present_error/shape)' with input shapes: [16,1,1,1], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [?,10].
This is with the my_loss_fn loss function.
If I use margin_loss I get this error:
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'W:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, MirroredVariable:{
      0: <tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(9, 9, 1, 16) dtype=float32>
    }), (None, MirroredVariable:{
      0: <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>
    }), (None, MirroredVariable:{
      0: <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(5, 5, 16, 256) dtype=float32>
    }), (None, MirroredVariable:{
      0: <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>
    }), (None, MirroredVariable:{
      0: <tf.Variable 'W:0' shape=(1, 32, 10, 16, 8) dtype=float32>
    })).

I'm not totally sure where to go from here, any help is appreciated!
